# App Rejectection for user Registration or Login?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store

We noticed that your app requires users to register or log in to access features that are not account-based.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to let users freely access your app’s non account-based features.

Apps may not require users to enter personal information to function, except when directly relevant to the core functionality of the app or required by law.[image]

Previously similar applications Apple is accepted now this applications is not accepting. Please help me frieds how to resolve

Comment: what is the app functionality? why user need to be login? if you are providing functionality based on user account then login should required, if all the users can access same thing then app do not require login functionality.

Comment: Every user inside application he made some Connects and he shared Business cards to other So login is Required. Based on UserID (user Login) we are providing some futures so login is required for this application.

Comment: if login is based on functionality then you can provide these scenario in that review reply so they will check you app based on these scenario. if they still reject it then you can do appeal on review board.

Comment: where I have to provide these details and what kind of details I have to provide for approval

Comment: you can check in bellow of your app rejection section in your account if there is any option for reply then you can reply from that. other wise while providing for review you can provide login credential in note and also provide scenario that why login is required.

Comment: Just reply in the resolution center of your apple account with your following answer.

Every user inside application he made some Connects and he shared Business cards to other So login is Required. Based on UserID (user Login) we are providing some futures so login is required for this application

Comment: I already provided login credentials

Comment: just reply  or I have to submit new version?

Comment: can please give replay